# How to create a grpc-over-rest proxy

Tags: grpc, envoyproxy

[Envoy's tutorial](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter) for creating a REST wrapper over a gRPC service starts with a `google.api.http` qualifier in the `rpc` definition like below, and generates the REST wrapper from that.

```
  rpc SayHello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/say"
    };
  }
```

Is there a way to do the opposite: use the above to generate a gRPC proxy on top of a REST service? Either with Envoy or some other proxy, or from scratch?

The basic scenario is my org has a bunch of services that communicate over gRPC. It's kind of a pain to test any service locally because it tends to force you also to bring in all the downstream services locally too, or create a tunnel to staging.

Instead, I want to be able to create a universal mock gRPC provider service that can run locally, takes any incoming gRPC request generically, looks up the corresponding definition in our protos repo, and uses the `google.api.http` qualifiers, as well as some custom qualifiers (`option (run_js) = async (req) => ...` for example) to perform any action and generate the response.

Handling raw gRPC generically is hard, so I was hoping I could create this mock provider service with a REST API, and then put some gRPC-over-REST proxy in front of that. That way, we could have a single mock service that runs locally, and whatever service we were currently testing would hit that via the proxy. I know how to set up a generic REST API; it's just the conversion from gRPC to REST that I'm struggling with.